# Error in sentences in bold: " Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer vector :("

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main()
    {

        int arrsize;
        int randset;
        int max;
        int min;
        int arr[arrsize];
        int i, j;
        int swap;
        float mean;

        printf("Input array size:\n");
        scanf("%d", &arrsize);

        printf("Input random set:\n");
        scanf("%d", &randset);

        printf("Input maximum possible value:\n");
        scanf("%d", &max);

        printf("Input minimum possible value:\n");
        scanf("%d", &min);

        // SORTING //

        for (i = arrsize; i > 0; i--)
            for(j = 1 ; j < i ; j++)

// Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer vector  //

                **if(arrsize[j-1] > arrsize[j])**
                {
                    swap        = arr[j];
                    arr[j]      = arr[j-1];
                    arr[j-1]    = swap;
                }   

        for (i=0; i < arrsize; i++)
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
        printf("\n\n");

        // MEAN //

        for(i = 0 ; i < arrsize ; i ++)
        {   
//Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer vector //
            **mean += arrsize[i];**
            mean/= arrsize;

            printf("The mean is %.2lf\n\n", mean);
        }

        // MEDIAN //


        if(arrsize%2 == 0)
            {
                printf("The median is %.2lf", (float)(arr[arrsize/2 -1] + arr[arrsize/2]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The median is %d", arr [arrsize/2]);
                printf("\n\n\n");
            }

            printf("The midrange is %.2lf\n\n", (float)(arr[0] + arr[arrsize - 1] / 2); 

    }


    void fillintarray(int myarray [], int arrsize, int min, int max, unsigned int randset)
    {
        int iter;
        srand (randset);
        for (iter =0 ; iter < arrsize ; iter++)
        {
            myarray[iter] = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
        }
    }
```

Hi there! I put the lines where there were errors in bold, and the error was 
"Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer vector"
This is an exercise for my ComSci class :) Help would be much appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: You need to use `arr` instead of `arrsize`, but this is just the tip of the iceberg: your array has undefined size, the program will crash as soon as you run it.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by it will crash soon? The arrsize is to be an input... so will it still crash? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Absolutely, it will. You declare `arr[arrsize]` before you input `arrsize` itself, so `arr` will be created with some junk size - whatever happens to be in the uninitialized memory of the `arrsize` variable.

Comment: Oh, so uh... how do you suggest I should fix this? I've fixed everything but when I try to use it, it just crashes. :) @dasblinkenlight

Comment: You need to declare the array *after* you read the `arrsize`.

Comment: For a second I thought the :( was part of the error and I was really excited...

Comment: @jozefg, sorry, I tend to use smileys a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error message is pretty descriptive - you accessing a scalar variable `int arrsize` with subscript operator `[]` which could only be applied to array or pointer type.

You probably want to check `j-1`-th and `j`-th array elements, you should use
`if (arr[j-1] > arr[j])`

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct but not really useful to the OP as he/she is probably a beginner

Comment: haha yeah, I'm a first year CS student ._. and nobody in my university wants to help (I've asked at least 5 people >_<

Comment: Oh Wow it actually worked when I switched arrsize to arr. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing between the array(`arr`) and its size(`arrsize`).

Comment: If you have an array variable `a` and an integer index `i` then isn't `a[i]` and `i[a]` functionally the same since it boils down to `*(i + a)` as opposed to `*(a + i)` and addition is commutative?

Comment: @DuncanACoulter Of course. But it has nothing to do neither with the question nor with my answer.

Comment: uhm, the arraysize is the user input,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the size of array , use `malloc` .

Use `int  *array = malloc(arraysize * sizeof(int));`**instead of** `int array[arraysize];`

And put it **after**`scanf("%d",&arraysize);`

And you also need **init the array before use it**.